# Text expansion in Vim

Tags: vim, macros

In Vim, I'd like to type…

```
1x1<TAB>
```

and have it expand to…

```
(r 1)(d 1)(l 1)(u 1)
```

and for…

```
2x4<TAB>
```

to expand to…

```
(r 2)(d 4)(l 2)(u 4)
```

How would I go about making this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need a small, fixed set of these, you can simply define `:iabb` (though they will expand with <kbd>Space</kbd>, not <kbd>Tab</kbd>). Alternatively, there are plugins like [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) -- they even do the expansion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> by default.

However, if you need expansion of arbitrary numbers, a fixed scheme won't work and you have to implement a custom mapping for `<Tab>` that extracts the keyword before the cursor and replaces it with the expansion, like this:

```
:inoremap <Tab> <Tab>$<Esc>:substitute/\<\(\d\+\)x\(\d\+\)\s*\%#/(r \1)(d \2)(l \1)(u \2)/e<CR>0f$s
```

This temporarily inserts a `$` placeholder to restore the original cursor position after the substitution; you could implement something better with `getpos()` / `setpos()`.

Comment: What does the `\%#` at the end of the pattern do?

Comment: It matches the current cursor position to avoid that a previous instance of the string is processed.