# Vim Macros Inserting Selected Text Into Latex environment

Tags: vim

Assume there is some Latex multiline formula code. After lines visual mode selection there must be macros that inserts before and after formula env enclosing code

I.e. from

```
formula
```

to

```
\begin{env}
formula
\end{env}
```

Can someone help to write designed macros?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text expansion in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062634/text-expansion-in-vim)